# Oracle SQL - Counting the continous number of weeks between two dates

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to count the continuous number of weeks between two dates, at the moment I can partially accomplish that by using

```
select
(next_day(TO_DATE('01-01-1994', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'MONDAY')-next_day(TO_DATE('01-01-1995',
 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'MONDAY'))/7 countinous_weeks
from dual;
```

I get 52 weeks have passed between the two dates but when I check the last week of '01-01-1994' I get 53 weeks.

```
select 
to_char(TO_DATE('31-12-1994', 'DD/MM/YYYY'),'ww') as last_week_test 
from dual;
```

It is fairly obvious to understand why this is happening but I would be grateful if someone could come up with a way of counting the number of weeks continuously without having to use next_day because that is where I believe the problem is.

Many thanks for any tips in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `trunc` function by day like this:

```
select (trunc(TO_DATE('01-01-1994', 'DD/MM/YYYY'),'d')-trunc(TO_DATE('01-01-1995',
 'DD/MM/YYYY'),'d'))/7  countinous_weeks from dual;
```

You should not use `next_day` because you can get out of the current week. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it's happening because you are effectively round up the number of weeks in the second case e.g. your first case is working how you want it?

If you are looking for whole weeks then the first answer is correct, if you are looking for all weeks then if there is a remainder add 1?

e.g.

```
select countinous_weeks, decode(countinous_weeks-52,0,trunc(countinous_weeks),trunc(countinous_weeks)+1)
from (
select (TO_DATE('01-01-1995', 'DD/MM/YYYY') - TO_DATE('01-01-1994','DD/MM/YYYY'))/7 countinous_weeks
from dual) wks
```